# this.someProperty is not a function in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to abstract some of my JavaScript code by adding functions as objects of properties. The ultimate goal is a dynamic way to render data using Google charts. Below is my `charts` object which right now works when I call it on the page. This is assuming a separate `config` and `util` object which have some other methods:

```
app.charts = {
  init: function(){

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package, wait until loaded
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(this.createChart);
  },
  createChart: function(){

    // draw charts to their id
    chartData = app.utils.getAjax(s.urls.dashUrl, function(data){

      // Convert to a table
      var jsonDataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

      // Select html element and draw the chart
      var chartJson = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('json'));
      chartJson.draw(jsonDataTable);
      this.dataTable();
    });
  },
  dataTable: function(){
    console.log("whatever");
  }

};
```

What i would like to do is abstract the `var chartJson = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('json'));` line so that I can give an option and switch to different charts instead of hard coding every chart I want (and thus make it so I can let the user choose chart type.

Whenever I try and write another method, I get a `google.visualization is undefined` error. I don't see why though because I don't call anything until after the google load callback in `init`.

To start simple I tried to take have the `dataTable:` function return a new `new google.visualization.DataTable(data);` and I received `ReferenceError: dataTable is not defined`.

I am not sure what is going on that these values can't be found or used, any help appreciated.

Comment: `this` inside of that callback isn't the object you think it is. `app.charts.dataTable` on the other hand should work.

Comment: @KevinB that is very interesting. I assume that `this` was actually referring to the `createChart` function, correct? I guess I am trying to adjust to some scoping stuff.

Comment: Nope, `this` will be whatever `app.utils.getAjax` gives it as a context, similar to how event handlers have the dom element as a context normally rather than whatever is in the scope the event handler was bound in.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I've just just writing some code thinking you meant one thing but I'm not sure it is now reading follow up comments... I'm posting it anyway just FYI:

```
app.charts = {
  init: function(){

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package, wait until loaded
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(this.createChart);
  },

  createChart: function(){

    // draw charts to their id
    chartData = app.utils.getAjax(s.urls.dashUrl, function(data){

      // Convert to a table
      var jsonDataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

      // Select html element and draw the chart
      var input = document.getElementById('user-input').value;
      this.chartType(input);
      this.dataTable();
    });

  },

  dataTable: function(){
    console.log("whatever");
  },

  chartType: function(input){

    switch(input)
    {
        case 'whatever':
            var chartJson = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('json'));
            chartJson.draw(jsonDataTable);
        break;
        case 'whatever2':
            // etc
        break;
    }

  }

};
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="user-input">
    <option value="whatever">whataver</option>
    <option value="whatever2">whataver2</option>
</select>
```